# Internet Explorer 9 Tabs Don't Show Content

Tags: windows-7, tabs, internet-explorer-9

Okay this is confusing but it is not that i don't see actual tabs but i don't see anything in browser. **[Take a look at this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEvjVfz06g8)**

**[Here are more details](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cucvgx7xDNs)**

It seems as new tab's window is covered by previous tab's content but you can see how cursor changes as i navigate to page elements located in a new tab's window and not previous. This happens frequently and i don't know what might be a problem.

**UPDATE 1:** [**This video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0u8xMfOJYHM&hd=1) shows better what is going on. Maximizing video will be better as you will see more details.

**UPDATE 2:** Internet Explorer really is buggy for me here. Not only it creates what it looks to be unresponsive new tab when following link, but it gives me these errors:

[image]

[image]

You can view full sized image by opening it in new tab/window.

**UPDATE 3:** After downgrading to 8.0 i now sometimes get blinking window. Sometimes i get message that says something like out of memory, **[but in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6GEEsvEnVQ&hd=1)** you can observe blinking window only.

**UPDATE 4:** I have now in addition to blinking windows the following message (which you can **[watch in video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-i3XCh1_4NI&hd=1)**):

```
Out of memory at line: 3
```

*DELL E6420*

*Windows 7 Enterprise*

*4GB of RAM*

*Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421*

Answer (score 2):

When something strange goes wrong with Internet Explorer it's often difficult to repair because it's tightly built in to Windows. This could be graphics driver related also, so check that you have the latest Windows 7 drivers for your particular graphics card.

In order of ease to perform/impact, here are some steps to try and reset IE9 in case it has gotten itself in a bad state:

- Disable any and all add-ons you have in IE, via Internet Options > Advanced > 'Manage add-ons' button
- Internet Options > Advanced (tab) > 'Reset' button
- Internet Options > Advanced (tab) > 'Restore Advanced Settings' button
- Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on/off > un tick IE9 reboot, come back and tick it again
- Follow [the steps here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/how-do-i-install-or-uninstall-internet-explorer-9) to revert back to IE8, then try re-installing IE9

Comment: Hmm reverting and reinstalling Internet Explorer creates more junk in registry.